# Image source of world political map for Google Maps overlay in Android?

Tags: google-maps, android, overlay

I have searched a lot. But I am not able to find some high resolution image of world map showing countries in different colors without label, which I can slice and use to create tile overlay in my Google Maps.

Any idea from where I can get a world image showing countries in different colors without labels?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  You say that you have searched a lot but can you edit your question to indicate where you have searched?  Potential answerers often look for evidence of prior research and even just listing a few sites that you looked on an why what was there did not meet your requirements may encourage them to answer, and avoid just repeating your steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have more options if you consider vector-data sources also. If you are a bit familiar with GIS you can render and export the shapefile with the look you want for you map. If not these are relatively easy GIS tasks and not too difficult to get into.  naturalearthdata.com has some nice [shapefiles](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/10m-admin-0-countries/) with world political boundaries. I think they have a column with numbers that can be used for the colouring so that no adjacent countries have the same colour. You would simply assign a colour to each number in the layout definition in your GIS (e.g. qgis) and there you are.

Comment: I tried that. But couldn't find how to read shp files. I downloaded the cultural data. But after that I was clueless how to use that data. Even on Google I couldn't find some good beginner level tutorial to start with. I have zero knowledge of GIS. Do you know any good tutorials ? Thanks a lot. Now I know that it is possible to generate from GIS data... I will do more research in this direction

Comment: For beginners I would choose QGIS to learn GIS. It is a free open source GIS Software. They have a beginners tutorial "A gentle introduction to GIS": http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/

Comment: I am able to make a high resolution image from the .shp file of world countries map. Can you guide me how to add different colors to it. I have added dbf file to qgis Thanks a lot